# Rewrite running total sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite the following SQL to make it more effecient (possibly using Oracle analytic functions but any effecient rewrite will do). The SQL currently works, it just take a while to run:-

Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM_REF 
(
  DEPT_ID VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, ID VARCHAR2(11 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, ID_TYPE VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, ITEM_CHARGE VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, ITEM_PAYMENT VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, ITEM_DATE DATE NOT NULL 
, REF_AMT NUMBER(14, 2) NOT NULL
)
```

Insert into Table:

```
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000001', '000000000000002', '11/JUN/09', '1550')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000003', '000000000000004', '23/OCT/09', '3100')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000005', '000000000000007', '02/AUG/10', '3500')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000008', '000000000000010', '15/DEC/10', '3500')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000003', '000000000000004', '14/APR/11', '0')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000012', '000000000000014', '14/APR/11', '3100')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000021', '000000000000022', '13/JUL/11', '3500')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000016', '000000000000018', '03/JUN/11', '1550')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000016', '000000000000018', '22/JUN/11', '0')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000017', '000000000000019', '22/JUN/11', '1550')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000005', '000000000000007', '13/JUL/11', '0')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000021', '000000000000022', '19/SEP/11', '0')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000021', '000000000000024', '19/SEP/11', '3500')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000023', '000000000000025', '21/NOV/11', '1550')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000027', '000000000000030', '03/NOV/14', '384')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000028', '000000000000030', '03/NOV/14', '247.8')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0004', 'O', '000000000000026', '000000000000029', '27/OCT/14', '2465')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0002', 'O', '000000000000001', '000000000000004', '07/JUL/10', '88.4')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0002', 'O', '000000000000001', '000000000000004', '13/JUL/10', '88.4')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0002', 'O', '000000000000001', '000000000000006', '17/AUG/10', '353.6')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0002', 'O', '000000000000001', '000000000000004', '21/AUG/10', '88.4')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0002', 'O', '000000000000001', '000000000000006', '21/AUG/10', '87.6')
INSERT INTO ITEM_REF VALUES ('POLLD', '0002', 'O', '000000000000001', '000000000000006', '25/AUG/10', '353.6')
```

Current Running Total SQL:

```
SELECT A.DEPT_ID, A.ID, A.ID_TYPE, A.ITEM_CHARGE, A.ITEM_DATE
, NVL((SELECT SUM(B.REF_AMT) FROM ITEM_REF B
        WHERE B.DEPT_ID     = A.DEPT_ID
          AND B.ID          = A.ID
          AND B.ID_TYPE     = A.ID_TYPE
          AND B.ITEM_CHARGE = A.ITEM_CHARGE
          AND B.ITEM_DATE   =
            (SELECT MAX(B2.ITEM_DATE)
                FROM ITEM_REF B2
                WHERE B2.DEPT_ID      = B.DEPT_ID
                  AND B2.ID           = B.ID
                  AND B2.ID_TYPE      = B.ID_TYPE
                  AND B2.ITEM_CHARGE  = B.ITEM_CHARGE
                  AND B2.ITEM_PAYMENT = B.ITEM_PAYMENT
                  AND B2.ITEM_DATE   <= A.ITEM_DATE)
        ), 0)
FROM ITEM_REF A GROUP BY A.DEPT_ID, A.ID, A.ID_TYPE, A.ITEM_CHARGE, A.ITEM_DATE
```

I have attempted to use Oracle analytic functions as shown below:-

```
SELECT A.DEPT_ID
, A.ID
, A.ID_TYPE
, A.ITEM_CHARGE
, A.ITEM_DATE
, (SELECT SUM(B.REF_AMT)
    FROM ITEM_REF B
    WHERE B.DEPT_ID   =A.DEPT_ID
    AND B.ID          =A.ID
    AND B.ID_TYPE     =A.ID_TYPE
    AND B.ITEM_CHARGE =A.ITEM_CHARGE
    AND B.ITEM_DATE   =
        (SELECT  C.ITEM_DATE
        FROM
            (SELECT  D.ITEM_DATE
                    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D.DEPT_ID, D.ID, D.ID_TYPE, D.ITEM_CHARGE, D.ITEM_PAYMENT ORDER BY D.ITEM_DATE DESC) RN
                FROM ITEM_REF D
                WHERE D.ITEM_DATE <= A.ITEM_DATE
                ) C
        WHERE C.RN =1
        )
    )
FROM ITEM_REF A
```

The reference to A.ITEM_DATE breaks this code because the inner SQL cannot reference table ITEM_REF A. My approach here is to use Oracle analytic function to return the max ITEM_DATE as of a given date from the main SQL table i.e ITEM_REF A.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can ask questions and get answers about problems you're having with software you've written, but it is not a "do my homework for me" or "do my job for me" site. When you ask a question you should include the code you've written **and the specific errors you're getting** or the results your program produces and an explanation of the results you expected. Without that there's really not much we can do to help you. Please edit your question to show what you've done and tell us what problems the code has. Again, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Can you also do a quick "create table #ITEM_REF " and some statements to insert some sample data into it so that we have got something to play with/ run it against

Comment: Also is B_ED supposed to be B2, or what is B_ED?

Comment: I have added more information around my attempts and sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Query with data grouping at beginning and sorting rows with `row_number`. I think it may be better if after grouping you have much less rows. Tried it against 750,000 rows, new version was faster.
But I prefer your query, it's more readable ;-)

```
with ds as (select dept_id, id, id_type, item_charge, item_date, item_payment, sum(ref_amt) ref_amt
  from item_ref
  group by dept_id, id, id_type, item_charge, item_date, item_payment),
dsp as (
  select ds1.dept_id, ds1.id, ds1.id_type, ds1.item_charge, ds1.item_date, ds2.ref_amt,
      row_number() over (partition by ds2.dept_id, ds2.id, ds2.id_type, ds2.item_charge, 
        ds2.item_payment, ds1.item_date order by ds2.item_date desc) rn 
    from ds ds1 join ds ds2 on ds2.dept_id=ds1.dept_id and ds2.id=ds1.id and ds2.id_type=ds1.id_type 
        and ds2.item_charge=ds1.item_charge and ds2.item_date<=ds1.item_date)
select dept_id, id, id_type, item_charge, item_date, sum(ref_amt) 
  from dsp where rn=1
  group by dept_id, id, id_type, item_charge, item_date
```

**Below is previous answer, not actual now:**

Maybe I'm wrong, but your currently running query finally returns simple sum, like in column `amt`.
I checked results three times adding sample records and I see no difference.

```
select dept_id, id, id_type, item_charge, item_date, 
    sum(ref_amt) amt, 
    sum(sum(ref_amt)) over (partition by dept_id, id, id_type, item_charge 
      order by item_date) amt_aggr
  from item_ref a
  group by dept_id, id, id_type, item_charge, item_date
```

If you want to obtain sum increasing you may use something like `amt_aggr`.

Comment: You're right, your code works well given the initial sample data. Please try it with the updated sample data. The ITEM_PAYMENT affects the sum of REF_AMT. Also thank your for your response.

Comment: Thanks for updated, better examples, tried some queries with them, but no success so far. One more hint - you can try to add composite index on (DEPT_ID, ID, ID_TYPE, ITEM_CHARGE, ITEM_DATE), it would probably much speed up execution.